# Inert primes in arithmetic progression

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a,m$ an integers s.t $(a,m)=1$. Let $K$ a quadratic field, I would like to calculate the natural density of the set

$$\{p \;\; \text{rational prime}\; /\; p\;\text{inert in}\; K,\; p\equiv a\pmod m\}$$

I think that is equal to $1/2\phi(m)$, but I couldn't prove that.

Comment: This is obviously false. Think about $p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ in $\mathbb Q(i)$.

Comment: The general idea is to say that both conditions correspond to the Frobenius of the prime p lying in certain conjugacy classes in $Gal(K/Q)$ and $Gal(Q(\mu_m)/Q)$. If these two fields are disjoint, then the Galois group of the compositum is the product of these two groups and the density is multiplicative. Otherwise, $K$ will be contained in the cyclotomic field and the density will be either $1/\phi(m)$ or $0$ depending on the image of $a$  in the map $Gal(Q(\mu_m)/Q) \to Gal(K/Q)$ being the non identity element or the identity element respectively.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn, Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Asvin, Thanks a lot for your comment.

Comment: @Asvin, if we write $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ what is the condition on $m$ and $d$ so that we have $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})\cap \mathbb{Q}(\mu_m)=\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: You can get a condition by looking at ramification. If $d_K$ is the discriminant of $K$, then the primes that ramify in $K$ are precisely those dividing $K$ while those ramifying in $Q(\mu_m)$ are those dividing $m$. So if $d_K$ is coprime to $m$, then the corresponding fields are disjoint.

Comment: In fact, you can prove a stronger statement that $K$ is contained in the cyclotomic field if and only $d_K|m$, you can probably find a proof with a little searching. Note that $K$ is contained in the cyclotomic field is equivalent to having a non trivial intersection...

Comment: Look up Chebotarev density (sometimes spelled differently).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not true in general. Take $K = \mathbb{Q}(i), a =3$ and $m = 4$. Then the density is just $1/2$ in this case. This is because a prime $p$ is inert in $K$ if and only if $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$. So the congruence condition implies already that $p$ is inert.

In general, saying that a prime is inert in $K$ can be written in terms of congruence conditions modulo $|d_K|$, where $d_K$ is the discriminant of $K$. So if $\gcd(d_K,m) = 1$, then the density is indeed $1/2\varphi(m)$. But otherwise you can get different densities occuring.